# I don't know why it's loading the picture twice in the first place. How can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPic();
  }, []);

  const getPic = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const pic = await axios({
        url: "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search",
      });
      const picUrl = pic.data[0];
      if (picUrl) {
        setData((prevData) => [...prevData, picUrl]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error = ${error}`);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>test</p>
      <div>
        {data.map((d) => (
          <div key={d.id}>
            <S.CatImg src={d.url} alt="" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I am practicing implementing infinite scrolling.
I think the getPic function should be executed only once because nothing is added to UseEffect's dependencies array.
But I don't know why the first render shows 2 or more pictures of cats. 
Please help.

Comment: Maybe because `useEffect` runs twice in `React.strictmode`

Comment: OMG I solved it. I had another problem, but thank you